# is this a schwa?

Tags: phonetics, ipa

Today, out of interest I tried to unround the /o/ sound of my native language and I got [this vowel sound](https://voca.ro/1hO98yaROrUX), is this vowel a schwa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, following [the IPA models](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/inter_chart_2018/IPA_2018.html). It is most like the majority pronunciation, and it is not more like some other vowel (e.g. ɤ, ɜ, reverse schwa.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Another question, did you meant [ɘ] by reverse schwa?

Comment: Yeah, if fell off my character-table.